# In Ruby is there an alternative and more elegant way to call a method than 'case - when'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, switch-statement, send

In Rails 3.1, I want to create an embedded object by using a create method that accepts parameter data, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this than the case method below:

```
def method_call(obj,data)
  case obj
  when 'a' then User.create_a(data)
  when 'b' then User.create_b(data)
  when 'c' then User.create_c(data)
  end
end
```

I would really like to do something like the following, but the this causes an error because of the data that I pass:

```
def method_call(obj,data)
  User.send("create_#{obj}")(data)
end
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not the syntax for `send`. `send` takes a method name and then its arguments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `send` method takes the same parameters given to the method being called:

```
User.send("create_#{obj}", data)
```

Whether or not this is the most elegant solution depends: I'd leave the decision-making process up to the `User` class, which could happen in a variety of ways (e.g., a send like this, a hash of `Proc`s, etc.) A factory service is another alternative.

```
User.create(how, data) # "how" is a, b, c
```

Wherever it lives, make it obvious–this makes it easy to extend, fix, and reason about.

Comment: Thank you.  That was exactly what I was looking for and I had not yet tried that structure.